# ld: exclude library from main .text section and move it to another section

Tags: ld, linker-scripts

I am trying to move a library to a designated portion in flash memory.

I do this as follows:

```
.text.freertos : ALIGN(0x1000) 
{
    FILL(0xdead)
    *libfreertos_lib.a:*(.text*)
} >PROGRAM_FLASH
```

When I put this AFTER my main section, it yields nothing. The section remains empty, I think because the linker is smart enough to realize it already put this library as part of the main section and there is no point in wasting memory.

I really would prefer to have a bunch of libraries AFTER the main .text section though. Is there also a way to EXCLUDE a library in the main .text section? I am looking for something like

```
EXCLUDE_<something>(*libfreertos_lib.a:*(.text*))
```

I know EXCLUDE_FILE exists, but I prefer not to list all .o files that belong to some library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up pushing that section to a separate part in flash.

```
MEMORY
{
  /* Define each memory region */
  PROGRAM_FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x60000000, LENGTH = 0xC0000 
  LIBRARY_FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x600C0000, LENGTH = 0x10000
  SRAM_DTC (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x10000 
  SRAM_ITC (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x0, LENGTH = 0x10000
}

.freertos : ALIGN(4) 
{
    FILL(0xdd)
    *libfreertos_lib.a:*(.text*)
} >LIBRARY_FLASH
```